# R geojson feature display with leaflet

Tags: r, leaflet, geojson, ggmap

I have a GeoJSON map that is rendering fine with leaflet and open street map tile from Rstudio IDE locally, however the map doesn't display the features and properties (embeded in the jeojson file) when clicked in the various regions of the map.  When hosting the file on github, github automatically picks it up and respond to the clicks - as seen on the figure.  Looked for the information in the help documents for R and couldn't find any information.

[image]

```
leaflet() %>% 
        addProviderTiles("Hydda.Full")  %>% 
        setView(lng = -77.03687, lat = 38.90719, zoom = 12) %>% 
        addGeoJSON(topoData, weight = 4, color = "red",fill = TRUE)
```

Comment: any chance you could share some of your data to make the example reproducible?

Comment: I guess you need to add `popup = ...` to your `addGeoJSON()` call.

Comment: epo3 - the file is too large to share here. But you can search on the net for any geojson file (there are many), you can use that to replicate. TimSalabim - can you be more specific?

Comment: Try `addGeoJSON(topoData, popup = "test") `. This should create a popup when you click on the feature.

Comment: If you want something similar to what you see in you image you would need to read your data using `x <- rgdal::readOGR` and the you can use `popup = mapview::addPopupTable(x)`

Answer (score 4):

There are 3 ways in which you can do it.

1) Have a property called 'popup' for each feature in your geojson. If there is one the Leaflet will bind a popup to that feature with the contents equal to the value of the 'popup' property
https://github.com/rstudio/leaflet/blob/master/javascript/src/methods.js#L493

The problem is if you don't have one and most geojson's won't have a 'popup' property, then you have to add on on the R side. i.e. convert geojson string to a list and iteratively add popup property to each feature and convert it back to geojson string.

2) Convert geojson to a sp object in R, and use the popup features of add(PolyLines/Polygons/Markers) etc.
This is not a bad option as the sp object handling is way more elegant that geojson string or list.

Demo http://rpubs.com/bhaskarvk/leaflet-geojson (I don't have popups there only label, but you get the idea).

3) A middle ground, use https://github.com/bhaskarvk/leaflet.extras  addGeoJsonChoropleth() which allows you to specify any property or a custom JS code to determine your popup content.
e.g. http://rpubs.com/bhaskarvk/geojson-choropleth

I like 3 the best coz it allows me to add a GeoJSON with no modification or conversion required on R side. The only issue there is the coloring is done on the JS side, and it uses chroma.js supplied pallets, while 1, and 2 allow you to use the coloring technique that is consistent with other add(Shape) methods.

Comment: Bhaskar - thanks for the detailed response. The three options you provided are useful and will provide how to add the popup.  However, what I was looking for was this: the geojson comes with the following information embedded: { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "OBJECTID": 1, "WARD": 8, "NAME": "Ward 8", "REP_NAME": "", "WEB_URL": "", "REP_PHONE": "", - is there a way to extract that information and display it as popup using the leaflet native graphic element (ex. addMarker)? github seems to  be doing exactly that.

Comment: Not sure if you extracted and displayed the content from geojson data on this example rpubs.com/bhaskarvk/leaflet-weather . If so that is what I am looking for, appreciate if you can share the code  for this.  Thanks again.

Comment: If I read you correctly you want to display every property of a feature in a HTML Table as the popup ?
That should not be hard to do, but you will have to build the HTML Table your self, either in R using approach 1 or 2, or in Javascript using approach 3.
The weather example uses data from a data.frame obtained as a result of an API call.
If you can share your geojson I can show you exactly how to do it, Thanks

Comment: Here is the link. https://raw.githubusercontent.com/abiyug/geojason-test/master/dc-ward-2012.geojson

Comment: Demo w/ all 3 approaches:
http://rpubs.com/bhaskarvk/geojson-popups
& code
https://github.com/bhaskarvk/geojason-test

Comment: Thanks Bhaskar. Excellent explanation!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a reproducible example that produces something similar to your image:

```
library(mapview)
library(geojsonio)

## write data to disk as GeoJSON
geojson_write(breweries91, file = "breweries91.geojson")

## read back into R as Spatial* object
dat <- geojson_read("breweries91.geojson", what = "sp")

## plot using mapview
mapview(dat)

## or use leaflet with mapview::popupTable
leaflet() %>% 
  addProviderTiles("Hydda.Full")  %>% 
  addCircleMarkers(data = dat, popup = popupTable(dat))
```

Obviously the writing to GeoJSON part is only necessary to show the proper import strategy to get `popupTable` compatible data structure. In general, when working with spatial data, I suggest using the proper spatial classes for R provided by packages `sp` and now also `sf` for vector data and `raster` for raster data.

Comment: TimSalabim - So the original question is to render interactive map using leaflet with ‘geojson data frame’. The  embedded data in the geojson file should pop on click/or mouseover, as is the case when hosted on github. The example you gave me convert the geojson df to spatial df. Leaflet fails to read the spatial df with the following error 'doesn't know how to get location data from object of class SpatialPolygonsDataFrame.' While I like the mapview example, that doesn't solve the issue for why leaflet + GeoJson  doesn’t produce pop up from RStudio IDE vs when it is hosted on github.

Comment: Ok, to be more precise, there is no default way in **leaflet** to render popups for any of the `add*` methods. It is up to the user to provide a suitable character string or html string to the `popup = ...` argument. In fact the `addGeoJSON` function doesn't even have a popup argument. Github most likely has a script running in the background that, when realising the data is in geojson format, will render a certain way and provide the data in popups. But that has nothing to do with the R **leaflet** package. Assuming this would be the same is a little optimistic.

Comment: Additionally, you should provide code highlighting how you read the data into R as this is actually the crucial bit. Why is reading it as a Spatial*DF not appropriate? Does the error you mention happen with the example I provide above?

Comment: TimSalabim - thanks for following up. I downloaded the shp file from uscensus and then converted the shape file to geojson  - then imported to R like so: dat1 <- geojson_read("Ward__2012.geojson", what = "sp"). Like I said this will render and display the content in the now sp file when using mapview(dat), however when using the leaflet functions addMarker or AddCircle etc - we get the error. With the example you gave using leaflet - the overlay is lost.

Comment: If you are working with polygons you need to use `addPolygons` not `addCircleMarkers`.

Comment: Additionally, there's no need to convert to geojson before reading into R. You can read shapefiles natively with `rgdal::readOGR()`.